# rails find_by three fields - is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to use `find_by` with more than 2 fields?

Like:

```
feedback = Feedback.find_by_field_a_and_field_b_and_field_c("A", "B", "C")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's possible in Rails 3, but is deprecated in Rails 4. So it'd be recommended to use this syntax instead (if using Rails 4):

```
feedback = Feedback.find_by(field_a: "A",field_b: "B",field_c: "C")
```

See the api documentation for [find_by](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by).

If you're still on Rails 3 then it'd be better to do this (for performance reasons and because it's closer to the Rails 4 syntax):

```
feedback = Feedback.where(field_a: "A",field_b: "B",field_c: "C").first
```

Comment: other alternative, you can also do `feedback.first`, no need to plug `.first` in `where` or you can also do `feedback.map` and get your object.

Comment: How about `Feedback.find_by_field_a_and_field_b_and_field_c("A","B","C")`

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
feedback = Feedback.where(field_a: 'A',field_b: 'B',field_c: 'C')
```